# How can I scroll the content of a TFlowPanel?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, vcl

Delphi implementation of the `TFlowPanel` control seems to lack an important feature of the C# version, the `AutoScroll` one.

The C# control with `AutoWrap= False` and `AutoScroll=True` behave like a horizontal *scrollable* list of controls.

How can i mimic the behavior of the C# version of the control ?

Thanks,
Alin

P.S.
I know i can use `TScrollBox` to get this behavior but `TFlowPanel` (in the not crippled version) allow for much more flexibility.

Comment: Have you tried embedding a TFlowPanel inside a TScrollBox?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create your **TFlowPanel** inside a **TScrollBox**, with the following properties:

- Align    : alLeft
- AutoSize : TRUE
- AutoWrap : FALSE

That should get you the behaviour you are after I think.

Comment: yes, that`s the behavior i wanted ... would be nice if that could be achieved with only one container control but that will have to do for now :) thank you

Comment: It could - you could derive a new control from TScrollbar incorporating that part of a TFlowPanel behaviour that you needed without any of the optional, additional capabilities that you don't need.  If you have need to re-use this a great deal, then the time invested in creating such a control could be well repaid, but if not then this sort of "mash-up" is perfect and what component based development excels at - creating things that are greater [in utility] than the sum of the parts.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to scroll vertically set

```
FlowPanel1.Align := alTop;
FlowPanel1.AutoSize := True;
FlowPanel1.AUtoWrap := False;
```

Comment: This setting doesn't work.  I am using Delphi XE5.  Both horizontal and vertical scrolling setting doesn't work too.

Comment: sorry I cant help I only have XE4

Answer (score 2):

For people who are looking for a working vertical scrolling method:

```
procedure TfrmSample.FixVerticalScroll(const AFloatPanel: TFloatPanel);
begin
  fFloatPanel.Align := alTop;
  fFloatPanel.AutoSize := True;
  fFloatPanel.AutoWrap := True;
  fFloatPanel.OnResize := OnFlowPanelResize;
end;

procedure TfrmSample.OnFlowPanelResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Fix: otherwise panel is not operating on the full width
  fFloatPanel.Align := alClient;
  fFloatPanel.Align := alTop;
end;
```